# Trying to upload a file via api

Tags: python, django, api, file-upload, python-requests

I want to programmatically upload a pdf file to an APP via API, from a Python + Django APP.

Their documentation says:

“In order to upload an invoice you must do a POST as from.data with key type “file” and value fiscal_document that refers to the file you are attaching.”

```
curl -X POST  https://api.mercadolibre.com/packs/$PACK_ID/fiscal_documents 
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-F 'fiscal_document=@/home/user/.../Factura_adjunta.pdf'
```

I´m trying to achieve this using requests as follows:

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, files={'fiscal_document': my_file_url}).json()
```

But I get the following response

```
{
    "message": "File cannot be empty",
    "error": "bad_request",
    "status": 400,
    "cause": []
}
```

Is my request call ok?

In the example there is a local path declared, but I need to get the file from an URL. Should I keep the “@” in the `-F 'fiscal_document=@/home/user/.../Factura_adjunta.pdf'`?

Should I upload a byte type?

And clues welcome. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

Following the suggestions I tried the following:

```
with open(esta_operacion.factura_pdf.url, 'r') as myFile:
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, files={'fiscal_document': myFile}).json()
    myFile.close()
```

But I get `[Errno 2] No such file or directory.......`

The file exists and I can download it.

Comment: You need to pass a file-like object . Try `response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, files={'fiscal_document': open(my_file_url, 'rb')}).json()`. Remember to close the file.

Comment: Just updated the info

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem, but you are sending the URL string not the content of it. You should read the URL first and then upload the content.

The following code will provide this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen(my_file_url) as f:
    my_file = f.read()
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, files={'fiscal_document': my_file})
```